# java file executed from command line but not from browser(apache)?

Tags: java, php, linux, bash, shell

I have a java file which is being triggered from a shell script. If I execute the shell script at command line it is executing the java file without any issues but if i execute this shell script from browser( i have a index.php which executes this shell script in linux server ) it is not executing the java file in shell script. The shell script is executed properly If I remove the java execution line from the shell script.

below is the error i received when executed from browser.

```
Error From browser:Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007fcf589ac000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Permission denied' (errno=13) # # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory. # An error report file with more information is saved as: # /tmp/hs_err_pid306.log

# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2726), pid=306, tid=140528680765184

#
# JRE version:  (7.0_51-b13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

Please help me on how I can fix this problem.. Stuck with this issue from last one week. :|

Answer (score 0):

Permission problem.
Probably you run this java file as a different user from a browser.

An error report file with more information is saved as: # /tmp/hs_err_pid306.log
What does this error say?

Comment: I have updated the log file.. But I would like to say that there was n o issue when I execute it from command line but i am getting above error only from browser.

Answer (score 0):

Issue you have is with the HEAP memory.You don't have set enough memory to run the application.

Default size of Heap space  in Java is 128MB on most of 32 bit Sun's JVM but its highly varies from JVM to JVM  e.g. default maximum and start heap size for the 32-bit Solaris Operating System (SPARC Platform Edition) is -Xms=3670K and -Xmx=64M and Default values of heap size parameters on 64-bit systems have been increased up by approximately 30%. Also if you are using throughput garbage collector in Java 1.5 default maximum heap size of JVM would be Physical Memory/4 and  default initial heap size would be Physical Memory/16. Another way to find default heap size of JVM is to start an application with default heap parameters and monitor in using JConsole which is available on JDK 1.5 onwards, on VMSummary tab you will be able to see maximum heap size.

By the way you can increase size of java heap space based on your application need and I always recommend this to avoid using default JVM heap values. if your application is large and lots of object created you can change size of heap space by using JVM options -Xms and -Xmx.  Xms denotes starting size of Heap while -Xmx denotes maximum size of Heap in Java. There is another parameter called -Xmn which denotes Size of new generation of Java Heap Space. Only thing is you can not change the size of Heap in Java dynamically, you can only provide Java Heap Size parameter while starting JVM. I have shared some more useful JVM options related to Java Heap space and Garbage collection on my post 10 JVM options Java programmer must know, you may find useful.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html#ixzz30FsKCqeT

If it's tomcat you have to set this Memory Variables in "catalina.sh".

Eg :  If you a starting the application through command Line :

/bin/java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M Djava.util.logging.config.file= **-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M**